# return max number in list function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to return maximum number of numbers matching? For example:

`def maximum_number([4, 5, 6, 5, 2])`

returns `2` because 5 is maximum number and appears twice.

Answer (score 3):

Put your list into a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and ask it for the top result:

```
from collections import Counter

def maximum_number(lst):
    return Counter(lst).most_common(1)[0][1]
```

The [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) returns the top N results by count; the code above asks for the 1 top result, takes that one result from the returned list and extracts the count only:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> lst = [4, 5, 6, 5, 2]
>>> Counter(lst)
Counter({5: 2, 2: 1, 4: 1, 6: 1})
>>> Counter(lst).most_common(1)
[(5, 2)]
>>> Counter(lst).most_common(1)[0]
(5, 2)
>>> Counter(lst).most_common(1)[0][1]
2
```

Comment: I haven't used counter before any other way ??

Comment: Yes there are other ways but `Counter` is kind of a canonical solution and there is no reason to do something else. Just read the [documentation for `Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: @R.I: you'd have to manually count, using a dictionary (keys are the values in the list, values are the number of times you saw that value), then take the maximum count from that. Since Counter is a dictionary object, really, there is little point in reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: After seeing Vineesh's answer, it occurred to me that it would be more intuitive to do `max(Counter(lst).values())`.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida that is what `Counter.most_common()` ultimately uses when the argument is `1`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I know the result is the same, but prettier and easier to remember than `(1)[0][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you..

```
lst = [4, 5, 6, 5, 2]    
max([lst.count(i) for i in lst])
```

Comment: This is hugely inefficient, executing O(N^2) steps. 10 elements is 100 steps, 1000 takes a million steps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using *Counters* as shown works great. However, it doesn't help to understand the pattern. So here is a recipe to do it manually

1. Create a empty dict
2. Loop over the input//list
3. Find that value, as key, in the dict

   - if it exist, increase the value by one
   - else add it, with a value of 1

When the loop is done, find the highest value in the dict and use its key

This all can be done effectively in Python, using `dict.get(key, 0)+1` and `dict.iteritems()` (for Python-2; items(), for Python-3).